# Как сделать задержку для отправки сообщения на Azure ServiceBus Queue?

Tags: .net-core, azure

Мне нужно отправить сообщение с задержкой в одну минуту, после чего моя AzureFunction обработает сообщение. Как можно это сделать в .NET Core 2.0 проекте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выставьте ScheduleEnqueueTimeUtc на то время когда вы хотите чтобы оно появилось. Например добавьте одну минуту к DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.